# PhpStorm code completion for base classes

Tags: phpstorm

I have a base class named `BaseSniff` and have derived several classes from this.

`BaseSniff` contains a member of type `PHP_CodeSniffer_File` called `$phpcsFile`.

When editing `BaseSniff` PhpStorm will autocomplete when using `$this->phpcsFile` but in the derived classes this does not work.

Is there a way of achieving this?

Here is how the base class is declared

```
 /**
 * Base class for all Cardstream code sniffs.
 *
 * The class is constructed from a 
 *     list of tokens to register 
 *     list of code violations to check
 * This class implements the 'process' method of the PHP_CodeSniffer_Sniff 
 * class.
 * Derived classes are able to execute code before the actual processing of 
 * the token via the 'preProcess' method.
 * The code violations are then processed and errors and warnings are reported.
 * 
 * A code violation can stop the processing of the remaining 
 * violations for the file.
 * 
 * @author      Graham Labdon <graham.labdon@cardstream.com>
 */
abstract class BaseSniff implements \PHP_CodeSniffer_Sniff {
    public function process(\PHP_CodeSniffer_File $phpcs_file, $stack_ptr) {
        $this->phpcsFile = $phpcs_file;
    }
    /**
     * Creates the sniff.
     * 
     * Initialises the sniff
     *
     * @param   array       $register           Array of tokens to register
     * @param   array       $code_violations    List of code violations to check
     * @param   string      $sniff_name         Name of sniff
     * @return  void
     */
    public function __construct(
        array $register, 
        array $code_violations, 
        $sniff_name
    ) {
        $this->firstCall = true;
        $this->registeredTokens = $register;
        $this->codeViolations = $code_violations;
        $this->sniffName = $sniff_name; 
    }
}
```

And here is a derived class

```
class MultilineFunctionCallSniff extends BaseSniff {
    public function __construct() {
        $violations = array();

        $register = \PHP_CodeSniffer_Tokens::$functionNameTokens;

        parent::__construct(
            $register,
            $violations,
            "MultilineFunctionCall"
        );
    }   
}
```

Comment: Please provide code sample of `BaseSniff` (how it's defined, especially that field) + what IDE tells (where completion does not work). You most likely doing something wrong (missing some bits) .. as it's a basic functionality that definitely works.

Comment: Edited question to show details

Comment: So .. where/what does not work? As I understand `$this->phpcsFile` is declared in parent `\PHP_CodeSniffer_Sniff` class?

Comment: In the base class I can type $this->phpcsFile and then ctrl+space to get completions. If I do the same in derived class I get no completions found

Comment: Sorry ... but that is very broad description. Need a bit more concrete .. as code sample is way too short and limited. But based on the info so far I may say: provide proper typehint for `phpcsFile`. Since it's declared on some parent class (that is not made by you) ... you can override it using PHPDoc for class comment via `@property` tag -- `@property \PHP_CodeSniffer_File $phpcs_file (optional description here)`)

Comment: That was the solution

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to add a @property tag in the doc block for the base class